# Ionic 2 android version fails

Tags: android, cordova, angular, ionic2

My ionic 2 project is android. Application works android 5.x.x or higher version. But application not work older versions. 
My project added plugin cordova-plugin-x5engine-webview. Project doesn't work.

Please help me

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Crosswalk plugin to your project:

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`

Find more details in pluign page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview